# rsync with chmod to a remote destination wont allow file permission

Tags: linux, backup, rsync, chmod

Trying to set up rsync to a remote server, but when I run the rsync some files are showing as denied permission

I have messed around with the localuser permissions also tried to rewrite the script, I can manually change file permission on the remote host and that works, but I want it done when I run rsync:

```
#/bin/sh                                                                         

rsync --progress --perms --chmod=a+rwx -e "ssh -i backuptest@remoteserver" --copy-unsafe-links -rz backuptest@remoteserver:/opt /var/log/backup/remoterserver
```

Results in:

```
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1505) [generator=3.0.6[]
```

Error:

```
Warning: Identity file backuptest@remoteserver not accessible: No such file or directory.                                              
receiving incremental file list                                                                                                       
rsync: opendir "path/of/file" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: opendir "path/of/file" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: opendir "path/of/file" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: opendir "path/of/file" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: opendir "path/of/file" failed: Permission denied (13)
and these are different paths to different files, so I got get some files that back up but then I get the permission denied
```

Comment: Why can't it access `path/of/file`?

Comment: that is what I am trying to figure out, it can back up other files in the directory, but wont back up certain files

Comment: Have you considered looking at the permissions for these particular files?

Comment: So the rsync will work if I individually go into each file and change permissions, but that would take way to long and I would need to go and make changes as new files appear, I would ideally like it all done when running rsync, not sure if that possible or if I am writting my script wrong

Comment: If you want to change the permissions on your files before transferring them, you should `chmod -R a+rX yourdir` first in a separate command. rsync's `--chmod` flag is for setting permissions on the remote.

Comment: @thatotherguy thank you I will give that a try